Can the localization $U^{-1} R$ also be constructed as $R[x_s : s \in U]/\langle s x_s - 1 : s \in U\rangle$?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let $U \subseteq R$ be a multiplicatively closed subset. Recently, in my Algebra I class, we learned about the localization $U^{-1} R$. We constructed this as a set of equivalence classes in $R \times U$, viewing the pair $(a, s) \in R \times U$ as $\frac{a}{s} \in U^{-1} S$.
My question is: Can $U^{-1} R$ also be constructed as $\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} \quotient{R[x_s \ : \ s \ \in \ U]}{\langle s x_s - 1 \ : \ s \ \in \ U\rangle}$? Certainly, there is a natural homomorphism
$$
\varphi: R \to \quotient{R[x_s \ : \ s \ \in \ U]}{\langle s x_s - 1 \ : \ s \ \in \ U\rangle}
$$
such that for every $s \in U$, $\varphi(s)$ is invertible. Hence, by the universal property of $U^{-1} R$, there is a unique homomorphism $\overline{\varphi}$ such that the following diagram commutes:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
R & \varphi & \\
\downarrow & \searrow & \\
U^{-1} R & \rightarrow & \quotient{R[x_s \ : \ s \ \in \ U]}{\langle s x_s - 1 \ : \ s \ \in \ U\rangle} \\
& \overline{\varphi}& \\
\end{array}
$$
The question is now whether $\overline{\varphi}$ is an isomorphism.

Have you tried defining a map in the other direction (using the universal properties of polynomial rings and quotients)?

Alternatively, even simpler: Can you verify that your ring satisfies the universal property of the localization?

@anankElpis Thank you very much, I've been able to construct an inverse by using the universal properties of polynomial rings and quotients.

Duplicate question. Please use site search.

We can explicitely construct an inverse for $\overline{\varphi}$.
Consider the map $\psi: R[x_s : s \in U] \to U^{-1} R, x_s \mapsto \frac{1}{s}$. This is defined via the universal property of the polynomial algebra. Now we have $\psi(s x_s - 1) = \psi(s) \psi(x_s) - \psi(1) = s \frac{1}{s} - 1 = 0$. Hence $\langle s x_s - 1 : s \in U \rangle \subseteq \operatorname{ker}(\psi)$. By the universal property of the quotient, we obtain a factorization
$$
\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}}
\begin{array}{ccc}
R[x_s : s \in U] & \psi & \\
\downarrow & \searrow & \\
\quotient{R[x_s \ : \ s \ \in \ U]}{\langle s x_s - 1 \ : \ s \ \in \ U\rangle} & \rightarrow & U^{-1} R \\
& \overline{\psi}& \\
\end{array}
$$
It remains to show that $\overline{\varphi}$ and $\overline{\psi}$ are mutually inverse.
Take any $\frac{a}{s} \in U^{-1} R$, with $a \in R$ and $s \in U$. Then we have $\overline{\psi}\left(\overline{\varphi}\left(\frac{a}{s}\right)\right) = \overline{\psi}([a x_s]) = a \frac{1}{s} = \frac{a}{s}$. Hence $\overline{\psi} \circ \overline{\varphi} = \operatorname{id}$.
We also have $\overline{\varphi}(\overline{\psi}([x_s])) = \overline{\varphi}\left(\frac{1}{s}\right) = [x_s]$. But now $\overline{\psi} \circ \overline{\varphi}$ and $\operatorname{id}$ are $R$-algebra homomorphisms which agree on the $[x_s]$, which generate $\quotient{R[x_s \ : \ s \ \in \ U]}{\langle s x_s - 1 \ : \ s \ \in \ U\rangle}$ as an $R$-algebra. Hence $\overline{\psi} \circ \overline{\varphi} = \operatorname{id}$.
I've posted a similar answer here:

Localization as a quotient ring


If you have posted a similar answer there, you should just report this question as a duplicate of that one.
